# Angularjs selectedOption not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, opencart

I have been trying to set the default selected option of the select box, don't know where I'm doing wrong.
here is my html

```html
<span ng-controller="sizeController" style="width:137px; float:left; margin:15px 0 0 10px; ">
  <label for="sizeSelect" style="float:left; color:orange">Size:</label>
  <select name="sizeSelect" id="colorSelect" style="width:90px" ng-model="size" ng-change ="onSizeChange(size)">
  <option ng-repeat="sizeoption in data.sizeOptions" value="{{sizeoption.id}}">{{sizeoption.name }}</option>
  </select>
</span>
```

controller goes here

```js
function sizeController($scope, $rootScope) {
$scope.data = {
 sizeOptions: [
   {id: 'Small', name: 'Small'},
   {id: 'Medium', name: 'Medium'},
   {id: 'Large', name: 'Large'},
   {id: 'XLarge', name: 'XLarge'}
 ],
  selectedOption: {id: 'Small', name: 'Small'}
};
$scope.onSizeChange = function(size){
  $rootScope.size = size;
};
}
```

By default first value in the select box is always empty.
dont't know why.
thanks in advance

Comment: It's empty because your ng-model variable "size" didnt exist in the controller and "undefined" is not in your optionslist so angular adds value="?" to the optionslist (the empty entry).

To set the select to an pre defined value you just have to set ng-model variable size to the value you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do yourself a favor by using `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat`ing the options yourself.

```
<select name="sizeSelect" 
    id="colorSelect" 
    style="width:90px" 
    ng-model="size" 
    ng-change="onSizeChange(size)"
    ng-options="sizeoption.id as sizeoption.name for sizeoption in data.sizeOptions">
</select>
```

Initialize by setting the model directly

```
$scope.size = "Small";
```

Comment: @lcycool thanks alot for your answer.
I have solved my problem. But I didn't get your point of using "ng-option" instead of <option>

Comment: While it is a valid solution by `ng-repeat` options manually, it is much more convenient and less error prone to use the built in `ng-options`. The feature I like most is that you can set to use `id` directly in `ng-model`, which save one level of translation while reading and writing data.

Answer (score 0):

I make solution for you. Use `ng-option` for select in angular.

[Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/mxc06whc/3/)

Here is more about `ng-option`:

[ngOption](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Answer (score 0):

The first value in the select box is always empty because it is undefined. The select dropdown (`ng-model="size"`) corresponds to `size` attribute of model, which is initially `undefined`. Initialize the size in the scope to one of the possible values like below, it will remove the undefined empty first option.

```
$scope.size = 'Medium';
```

But even if you initialize size to 2nd or 3rd option it will still select the first option, now you have to use `ng-select` to select the correct value  `ng-selected="size == sizeoption.id"`

Complete solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaitanyaMunipalle/hd8moLhy/)